# If statement always evaluated, something always prints in cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, indexpath

My problem is I returned the rows to be `count`, as a result when I try to run my code, the array in the UserDefaults is only evaluated to the first 4 objects. And even if the if statement = false, the. row will have a title as `title` and detailText as `subtitle`

Problems are:

- ooo (long array) starts from 0 when doing indexpath.row and goes to count
- if statement always is evaluated

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventO", for: indexPath)

       rol = (UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "data") ?? [String]())[indexPath.row]

       self.title = dat

       let ooo = (UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "data") ?? [String]())
       ///This function starts from 0 when doing indexpath.row and goes to count
       ///This is the main problem
       if ooo != []{
           if ooo[indexPath.row] == dat{
               cell.textLabel?.text = (UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "array") ?? [String]())[indexPath.row]
               cell.detailTextLabel?.text = (UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "dae") ?? [String]())[indexPath.row] + ": " + (UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "array2") ?? [String]())[indexPath.row]
           }
       }
       return cell
   }
  ```

Comment: Unrelated but using `UserDefaults` as data source is horrible. Don't do that.

Comment: I do not store very secret information though

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do.  You should fetch your array once and have that in a property.  What is `dat`? Are you trying to filter your array?  You should filter once and ensure that `numberOfRows` returns the correct number of rows.

Comment: dat is the date that was pressed on calendar

Comment: I am trying to take the index of dat and use it for ooo

Comment: Why are you reading UserDefaults so many times instead of using a class property and why many arrays instead of using a custom struct for your data, this code will be very hard to maintain. You really need to look over your data model

Comment: Right, so you should use that to produce a filtered array that you save in a property and that array should provide the data for your table.  You then reload the whole table

Comment: @Paulw11, I do not understand, I tried doing this ```func filterCont(){
        self.newArr = self.ooo.filter{ user in
            let usern = user as? String
            return(usern?.lowercased().contains(dat.lowercased()))!
            
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
        print("yarr \(newArr)")
    }``` can you please demonstrate?

Comment: That looks about right; You then need to ensure that your `numberOfRows` and `cellForRow` use `self.newArr`

Comment: I solved my problem thanks Paul!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone I found a problem,I accidentally inserted an extra if statement. The resulting code is:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventO", for: indexPath)
    let gog = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "array") ?? [String]()
    let log = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "array2") ?? [String]()
    let rog = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "dae") ?? [String]()
    for i in 0...ooo.count-1{
        if ooo[i] == dat{
            see.append(gog[i])
            lee.append(log[i])
            mee.append(rog[i])
        }
    }
    rol = (UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "data") ?? [String]())[indexPath.row]
    self.title = dat
    if ooo != []{    
            cell.textLabel?.text = see[indexPath.row]
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = mee[indexPath.row] + ": " + lee[indexPath.row]

    }
    return cell
}
```